# Search Form Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this search function that I'm trying to figure it seems to be not working.. I have 2 search function one is for the main page which contains a list of buildings and the other one is on each pages which contains the offices.The main page search is working but the search for offices doesn't and it searches the main page not the one that's displayed on the page. Heres the code for search for offices.. Whats the problem here?

Heres my code for my building search this is working

-BuildingController.php

```
$search = \Request::get('search');
  $buildings = Building::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate();
  return view('buildings')->with('buildings', $buildings);
```

-buildings.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'/','role'=>'search']) !!}
       <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
         <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
             <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Search</i>
               </button>
             </span>
       </div>
         {!! Form::close()!!}
```

Heres my code the office search and this is not working

-OfficeController.php

```
  $searchoffice = \Request::get('searchoffice');
    $offices = Office::where('name','like','%'.$searchoffice.'%');
    return view('$offices')->with('$offices',$offices);
```

-building.blade.php

```
  {!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'/','role'=>'$searchoffice']) !!}
       <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
         <input type="text" name="searchoffice" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
             <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Search</i>
               </button>
             </span>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello TeamPlar Jarj,

```
$searchoffice = \Request::get('searchoffice');
$offices = Office::where('name','like','%'.$searchoffice.'%')->get();
$data['offices'] = $offices
return view('$offices',$data);
```

see the code. it issue "->get()" not added

Comment: The problem is everytime I clicked the search button for the offices it redirects me to the main page

Comment: still the same as before..  take a look at the code for my 2 search form above @Sagar Patel

Answer (score 0):

> office.blade.php (Blade file)

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'/office/search','role'=>'$searchoffice']) !!}
   <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
     <input type="text" name="searchoffice" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Search</i>
           </button>
         </span>
   </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

> web.php (Routes)

```
Route::get('office/search', 'App\Http\Controllers\OfficeController@search');
```

> OfficeController.php (Controller)

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    $searchoffice = $request->searchoffice;
    $offices = Office::where('name','like','%'.$searchoffice.'%')->get();

    $viewData = [
        'offices' => $offices,
    ];
    return view('office', $viewData);
}
```

Comment: {!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'/','role'=>'$searchoffice']) !!} 

I guess theres a conflict between this 'GET', 'url'=>'/'    cause I use this one for the building search.. what url should i use for office cause everytime I click the search button for office search it redirects to the building page
@Milan Akabari

Comment: The name of my blade file is building.blade.php